# Show existing value in dropdownlist

Tags: asp.net, razor, webmatrix

I have a webgrid that already show values from my database. When a user clicks to edit, I want one of the field Status to be displayed as a dropdownlist. Below is my code:

```
@{
var db = Database.Open("doctors"); 


var statusResults = db.Query("SELECT Distinct Status FROM cpd_certificates")
                    .Select(category => new SelectListItem {
                     Text = category.Status
                     }); 

    }
  //html code
         <div class="row">
             <span class="label"><label for="status"> Status:</label></span>
             @Html.DropDownList("Status",null, statusResults )
           </div>
```

My dropdownlist list appears but I want the existing value to show of which the user can now change.

Answer (score 0):

Tried and tested: See this site for more tutorials http://www.mikesdotnetting.com/Article/176/WebMatrix-and-jQuery-Forms-Part-2-Editing-Data

```
@{
var db = Database.Open("doctors"); 


var stat = db.Query("SELECT Distinct Status FROM cpd_certificates");

   }
     <div class="row">

     <select name="status" id="edit-status">
                <option value="">-- Select Status --</option>
            @{
                foreach(var statusResult in stat) {
                     <option value="@statusResult.Status" 
                 selected="selected">@statusResult.Status</option>
                }
            }
            </select>


      </div>
```